# error after renew expiry date of client secret

Tags: provider-hosted-app

I have renewed the expiry date of client secret by one year and it gets reflected successfully.

However I have update same in client secret(new) and in secondary client secret(old client secret)

After deployment it is giving error as below :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. 

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1399
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2WebRequest.GetResponse() +226
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request) +57

[RequestFailedException: Token request failed.]
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request) +156
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(String refreshToken, String targetPrincipalName, String targetHost, String targetRealm) +115
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(SharePointContextToken contextToken, String targetHost) +103
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.SharePointAcsContext.<get_UserAccessTokenForSPHost>b__9_0() +26
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.SharePointAcsContext.RenewAccessTokenIfNeeded(Tuple`2& accessToken, Func`1 tokenRenewalHandler) +58
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.SharePointAcsContext.GetAccessTokenString(Tuple`2& accessToken, Func`1 tokenRenewalHandler) +13
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.SharePointAcsContext.get_UserAccessTokenForSPHost() +59
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.SharePointContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost() +14
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.Controllers.ReferenceController.GetTechnicalDataSearchFieldsList() +54
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.Controllers.ReferenceController.EnsureSearchFormDropDownLists(ReferenceSearchViewModel referenceSearchViewModel) +86
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.Controllers.ReferenceController.Search() +223
   Innofactor.Poyry.PRP.ReferenceFormAddinWeb.Controllers.ReferenceController.Search(ReferenceSearchViewModel referenceSearchViewModel) +204
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +169
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9748665
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159
```

Comment: Where did you update the client id ? in web.config ? Did you update the client id and secret in azure portal as well ?

Comment: yes updated the client secret and secondaryclientsecret in web.cofig in visual studio and published. how can I update secret in azure portal?